# Android emulator in Eclipse significantly slower

Tags: android, api, sdk, emulation

I'm having a recent issue since two days ago. Before that I was running the android emulator (API versions 8 y 15) without any significative delay. But since these two days the starting up of the emulator has turn into unbearable time delay, the fifteen API version lasts around two hours, and the eight API version could delay more than 8 hours.

I have tried to reinstall the SDKs, erasing the AVDs without results. I have enabled the snapshot option, but the mentioned delay keeps the work awfully slow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the phase that is keeping the launch? How do you launch the emulator? Is the delay only in eclipse or also when you run the emulator from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the following:

```
emulator.exe -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim -avd avd
```

or to use gfx acceleration

```
emulator -avd <avd_name> -gpu on
```

if that wont work, give http://www.android-x86.org/ a chance ;)

As u already enabled the snapshot option, I dont have to name it again.

Furthermore:
[Can I tweak my android emulator to make it fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968170/can-i-tweak-my-android-emulator-to-make-it-fast)
[Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)
[Why is the Android emulator slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399071/why-is-the-android-emulator-slow)
[Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)
[Unbearably slow android emulator -- is there a fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210198/unbearably-slow-android-emulator-is-there-a-fix)

Comment: It seems both options of the emulator command achieve a sensitive reduction in the startup time (although the second one isn't compatible with the snapshot option). I have spread the option change to the eclipse IDE (Window->Preferences->Android->Launch->Default emulator options) and it seems to be working faster in any case. I will consider the android x86 option in the near future.


Still I wonder what change since the last week until the day before yesterday. 


Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your startups are taking **hours**? Something is seriously wrong. I'd check your development machine to see if it is out of disk or fragmented or thrashing.  Maybe check that the AVDs aren't declaring too much virtual SD.

Comment: No, I have a 2 weeks development machine, and a barely used HD with plenty of spare HD space. I have checked (again) the AVD settings and are fixed at the default values (Ram Size 512).

I'm launching the emulator from eclipse IDE. Also mention that I was developing the android tutorials, concretely this [one](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's much faster if you run Android on a virtual machine. You can follow my guide on setting it up, here http://www.bobbychanblog.com/2011/07/faster-android-emulator-alternative-using-virtualbox/